# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 IONIC

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework

I developt a Ionic project with this : 
http://masteringionic.com/blog/2016-12-15-using-php-and-mysql-with-ionic/
and i have the error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

when i want to insert a new client on my database.

I have a lot of client, I can have a list of all my client. In my database, i have the table with id, nom (name), and mail.

my php file :

```
<?php
[...]
   // Determine which mode is being requested
   switch($key)
   {

      // Add a new record to the technologies table
      case "create":

         // Sanitise URL supplied values
         $id            = filter_var($obj->client_id, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $nom            = filter_var($obj->client_nom, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
         $mail           = filter_var($obj->client_mail, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);

         // Attempt to run PDO prepared statement
         try {
            $sql    = "INSERT INTO client(id, nom, mail) VALUES(:client_id, :client_nom :client_mail)";
            $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':client_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':client_nom', $nom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':client_mail', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Bravo le client ' . $nom . ' a été ajouté à la base de données'));
         }
         // Catch any errors in running the prepared statement
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
            echo $e->getMessage();
         }

      break;



    [...]
?>
```

My html file :

```
              <ion-item-group>
                 <ion-item-divider color="light">Id du client *</ion-item-divider>
                 <ion-item>
                    <ion-input
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Entrer un id"
                       formControlName="client_id"
                       [(ngModel)]="clientId"></ion-input>
                 </ion-item>
              </ion-item-group>

                <ion-item-group>
                   <ion-item-divider color="light">Nom du client *</ion-item-divider>
                   <ion-item>
                      <ion-input
                         type="text"
                         placeholder="Entrer un nom "
                         formControlName="client_nom"
                         [(ngModel)]="clientNom"></ion-input>
                   </ion-item>
                </ion-item-group>


              <ion-item-group>
                 <ion-item-divider color="light">Mail du client *</ion-item-divider>
                 <ion-item>
                    <ion-textarea
                       placeholder="Entrer un mail"
                       formControlName="client_mail"
                       rows="6"
                       [(ngModel)]="clientMail"></ion-textarea>
                 </ion-item>
              </ion-item-group>


              <ion-item>
                 <button
                    ion-button
                    color="primary"
                    text-center
                    block
                    [disabled]="!form.valid">Valider</button>
              </ion-item>


           </ion-list>
        </form>
     </div>
  </div>


</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you reduce your question down to your database schema and an example of a failed query as well as a few example data sets? This way someone might be able to help you faster.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand what you mind

Comment: That is a lot of code you posted here. It might be difficult for the others to pinpoint the exact problem. You could also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for another explanation how to reduce the text.

Comment: I reduce my code

Comment: You are missing , (comma) after :client_nom